# Smooth UI updates tens times per second?

Tags: wpf

There are a lot of topics about different drawing approaches in WPF. Starting from Shapes and Polygons, ending with low-weight DrawingVisual and BitmapCache.

However, when it comes to frequent redrawing, say, moving line once per 16 ms (equal to 60 times per second), it appears to be choppy. And none of these approaches seems to provide required update frequency and smooth movement.

So the question is, how can it be achieved?

**NOTE:** I came up with this question after describing my issue in details in another topic: [How to achieve smooth UI updates every 16 ms?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23889294/how-to-achieve-smooth-ui-updates-every-16-ms)

Comment: How about WPF animating the control instead of a background thread?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution was found. Using CompositionTarget.Render is the way to go!
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms748838%28v=vs.110%29.aspx